# Passport.js authtication always returning FailureRedirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Hello I am new to Passport.js, I am trying to implement the passport authenticate method but I am always having the failureRedirect as a result.
All I want to know is if there is a way to console the error causing this failure or not.

Here is my code:

```
    app.post('/platform/adminsignin', passport.authenticate('platformlocal', {
    successRedirect: '/platform/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/platform/adminlogin',
    failureFlash: true,
}), function (req, res, info) {
    logger.info('Function should not execute');
});
```

I am always being redirected to adminlogin, I want to know if there is a way to get the reason of this failure.
Any advice could help, thanks.

Comment: What is `platformlocal`? Where is the passport configuration? You can try to log something in the callback function, but usually it's simpler to debug the process using your debugger.

Comment: Could you please explain how could I use use the callback function?

Comment: First, you have to answer my questions, otherwise, no, I can't help you. I don't know and didn't find `platformlocal`. I don't know how it is configured. Most (or all) strategies expect a callback function for verification.